# database for tags - updating many-to-many tables with unique columns

Tags: python, database-design, sqlalchemy

I'm not very experienced with databases and might be on a completely wrong track.

I have two tables, links and tags, with an association table. I'd like to update this database with an input that looks like `row = [tag, link]` but want to make sure that I do not add any tags or links that already exist. So I'm testing first whether the link exist, then whether the tag exist and finally whether the association exist.

The tables look like this:

```
tagslinks_assoc = Table(
    'tagslinks', Base.metadata,
    # Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),  # Not sure if this is required
    Column('tagid', Integer, ForeignKey('tags.tagid')),
    Column('linkid', Integer, ForeignKey('links.linkid')))

class Tags(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'    
    tagid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag   = Column(String, unique=True)
    links = relationship("Links", secondary=tagslinks_assoc, backref="tags")

class Links(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'links'    
    linkid    = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    link      = Column(String, unique=True)
```

I'm checking whether the link and tag exist like so:

```
link = session.query(Links).filter(Links.link == row[1]).first()
tag = session.query(Tags).filter(Tags.tag == row[0]).first()
```

How would I update the association between tag and link if both exist already but aren't connected yet?

Is there something in sqlalchemy and/or database relationships in general which makes the whole approach superfluous?

I was working off [this example](http://xsnippet.org/359350/) for understanding how to create a many-to-many relationship however my fields are both unique. Maybe they shouldn't be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.  Relationships are list-like by default, so simply appending an item will create a new association.  Instead, make them set-like to detect duplicates.  The thing in the set needs to override `__hash__` so that duplicates are detected properly.

```
class Tags(Base):
    # ...

    links = relationship(
        'Links', tagslinks_assoc,
        collection_class=set,  # use a set to hold the collection
        backref=backref('tags', collection_class=set)
    )

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.__class__, self.tag))  # any Tag with the same name hashes equal

class Links(Base):
    # ...

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.__class__, self.link))
```

Now get the tag, and add it to the link.  If it already exists, nothing will happen.

```
tag = session.query(Tags).filter(Tags.tag == 'my_tag').first()
link = session.query(Link).filter(Links.link == 'my_link').first()

link.tags.add(tag)  # if it's already present, the hash will compare equal and nothing will happen
session.commit()
```

See documentation about [collection_class](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.collection_class).

Regarding your tagslinks_assoc table, in most cases each table should have a primary key.  In this case the key would be a compound of tagid and linkid.

```
tagslinks_assoc = Table(
    'tagslinks', Base.metadata,
    Column('tagid', Integer, ForeignKey('tags.tagid'), primary_key=True),
    Column('linkid', Integer, ForeignKey('links.linkid'), primary_key=True)
)
```